Expo drawer navegacion
Estoy implementando drawer navigation para una app en expo pero me encuentro que al implementar  me lista todo las pantallas y componentes dentro del drawer, aun asi colocando solo una pantalla. Adjunto codigo

// Expo
import { Stack } from 'expo-router';
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { Drawer } from 'expo-router/drawer';

// React-native
import { Button, View, Image } from 'react-native';

// Views
import MainHome from './homeScreen';

// Images && Icons
const selfie = require('../assets/man.avif');

const RootLayout = () => {
  return(
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Drawer>
        <Drawer.Screen 
        name="homeScreen"
        options={{title: 'Reportes Cercanos'}}
        />
      </Drawer>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>

  )
}

export default RootLayout;

La distribucion del proyecto es basica y esta asi.


Solucionado:
Lo que se hizo fue poner _layout.tsx dentro de el grupo (private) que son las vistas que quiero que se vean en el drawer.
(private)
 _layout.tsx
 homeScreen.tsx
 ...

